# Функция добавления замечаний и предложений

Tags: python

Нужно написать, используя функцию, добавления замечаний и предложений.
Есть магазин:
Я так понимаю нужно создать отдельный словарь в который будет записываться и выводиться предложение или замечания от покупателя. Я думаю ключ это товар содержащий сообщение от пользователя который он вводит сам.
Подскажите как это сделать.

```
shop = {
    "мучное": {
        "хлеб": 200
    },
    "молочное":{
        "молоко":50
    },
    "мясное": {
        "говядина":500
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shop = {
    "мучное": {
        "хлеб": 200
    },
    "молочное":{
        "молоко":50
    },
    "мясное": {
        "говядина":500
    }
    "Замечания":{}
}

fail = input("Напишите замечание")
author = input("Как вас зовут по имени и фамилии? ")
shop["Замечания"][author] = fail
```

Вам должно помочь понять как решить вашу проблему